# Flutter -Widget Text, not updating when value change even with SetState

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-state, flutter-dialog

I have created a container. His child is a text.
When I tap on the container/text, it display a modal and a Picker.
Then, the user can select a value. Press the confirm button and my text widget should change to display the value selected by the user.
But in my case, it is not updating the value of the text widget. I have used that in the past and it was working very well. But here it is not and I do not see why. I am on this since 8:00. A little help would be appreciated. Many thanks.

```
int valuePickerUnitSelected =0;
String unitCount = '';
int unitCountInt;
String goal = "";

List <String> unitForHabits = ['Count', 'Minute(s)','Hour(s)','Gramme(s)', 'Pound(s)'];

class AddingHabitDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddingHabitDetails({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AddingHabitDetailsState createState() => _AddingHabitDetailsState();
}

class _AddingHabitDetailsState extends State<AddingHabitDetails> {
  BuildContext get ctx => null;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      //drawer:  new MyMenu(), //TODO a remettre
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Habits'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          titleZone('Name'),
          textFieldHabits('Habit name', context),
          titleZone('Goals'),
          FlatButton(

            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                if (unitCount.length < 2 )...[
                  Container(
                      width: 65,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue,
                          ),
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),

                      child:
                      Center(child: Text(
                          'Time', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,))))
                ]
                else
                  ...[
                    Container(
                        width: 65,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue,),
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(20))),
                        child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                            unitCount, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,))))
                  ],
              ],
            ),

            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                showModalBottomSheet(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return ShowPickerUnite(unitForHabits);
                    });
              },
              );
            },
          ),
          //ChipGoalV3(ctx),// ChipGoal(),
          textFieldHabits('Goals', context),
          titleZone('Frequency'),
          textFieldHabits('Frequency', context),
          titleZone('Time Range'),
          titleZone('Reminder'),
          titleZone('Habits Term'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

```
//########################################################################

class ShowPickerUnite extends StatefulWidget {
  List<String> myListUnit;
  ShowPickerUnite(this.myListUnit, {Key key}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  _ShowPickerUniteState createState() => _ShowPickerUniteState(
      myListUnit);
}

class _ShowPickerUniteState extends State<ShowPickerUnite> {
  List <String> myListUnit;

  _ShowPickerUniteState(this.myListUnit);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xffffffff),
              border: Border(
                bottom: BorderSide(
                  color: Color(0xffffffff),
                  width: 0.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                CupertinoButton(
                  child: Text('Cancel'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 16.0,
                    vertical: 5.0,
                  ),
                ),

                DefaultTextStyle(
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  child: Text('Select what you want'),
                ),

                // Text('Energy Needed', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.black),
                // ),

                CupertinoButton(
                  child: Text('Confirm'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {

                      unitCount = unitForHabits[valuePickerUnitSelected];
                      print(unitCount);
                    });
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 16.0,
                    vertical: 5.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            //width: 360,
              height: 200,
              decoration:BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0)),
              ),
              child: CupertinoPicker(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white ,
                  useMagnifier: true,
                  magnification: 1.3,
                  scrollController: FixedExtentScrollController(initialItem: 0),
                  itemExtent: 25,

                  children: [

                    for (String name in myListUnit)
                      Center(
                          child:Text(name)),
                  ],
                  onSelectedItemChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      valuePickerUnitSelected = value;
                      // taskEnergy = myListEnergy[valuePickerEnergySelected];
                      // taskNewValue ['task_Energy'] = taskEnergy;
                    });
                  }))
        ]);
  }
}
```

```
Widget inputNameHabit (){
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Text ('Name Habits',style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 25,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
  );
}

Widget titleZone (String _titleName){
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Row(
      children: [
        Text ( _titleName,
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 25,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

Widget textFieldHabits (String item,context){
  return TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintText: item,
      filled: true,
      fillColor: Colors.grey[300],
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)
      ),
    ),
  onTap: (){

    Navigator.push(context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => HabitGoalUnitSelection(), //TODO MODIFIER route selon source
      ),
    );
  },);
}
```

Comment: I think I am missing `unitForHabits` can you include this, Also I think you can provide minimal widget to showcase the error. More about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I have added the list. I am not getting an error. the text widget is not updated. To update it, I must go to the previous view and then call again this view

Comment: Isit not updating on dialog UI or after on the main UI. Also using global variable like this isnt a good idea.

Comment: in my code, this list is in a const.dart, where I store value that are const and will not change

Comment: I would recommend using state-management like riverpod/bloc, you can follow my answer section,

Comment: I do not know what is riverpod/bloc. I will investigate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait for the dialog to finish and then call `setState` to update the UI.

Modify this way

```dart
onPressed: () async {
  await showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return ShowPickerUnite(unitForHabits);
      });

  setState(() {});
```

Comment: glad to help, also you can get data on `pop` and update on parent widget here. You can find more about [showDialog](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html)